# JTabbedPane - Content does not get created

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, tabs, jtabbedpane

I have the problem of a non displaying swing component. Here is how I have structured my code:

Thats my `SelectionComponents` class:

```
public void init() {
    placeSelectionWithButtons();

}

private void placeSelectionWithButtons() {

    JPanel selectionArea = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    marketList = new JComboBox();
    countryList = new JComboBox();

    selectionArea.add(marketList);
    selectionArea.add(countryList);

    repaint();

}
```

With the init function I am initializing the method to Place the Buttons and Comboboxes.
Furthermore I want to put everything together in my `MainPanel` class:

I am just initializing this one method(will initialize more later!!!):

```
public void init(){

    log.info("enterMainTabPanel init method");

    selectionPanel.init();

}
```

Finally I am adding it to the method, when I created the TabBar:

```
    public void createTabBar() {

        log.info("add Tab Bar");

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        //sets the first Tab
        mainTabPanel.init();    
        tabbedPane.addTab("Main", mainTabPanel);
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);
...
```

My problem is that my TabBar gets created and all methods are callen(have viewed the log entries). However nothing displays inside the Tab Content?

Any recommendations what I should change or add?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thx a lot for your answer! Will try to do that, however, I thing the error is somewhere in my application structure, therefore an MCVE will be hard. Nevertheless, I will try to create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component hierarchy is not clear from your example code.

First check if you have added the `TabBar` to the content pane of your frame. Then verify that you have added the `selectionArea` to your `TabBar`.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Any recommendations on how to do this elegantly? I would appreciate your answer!

Comment: Sure. Make createTabBar return the JTabbedPane and add it to your frame.getContentPane();